# Sending a mobilepush message to specific device in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We've tried to send a message to **a specific device**, which we can specify via the device's **system token** on journey's decision split.

But the result was that it's sent to all devices the contact owns.

Was there any case that you've set the push messages to be sent only to a specific device?

Comment: What's the use case? Do you anticipate that a lot of your users will have multiple devices? Also, when creating a list manually there's a de-duplicate checkbox. See if that's available for you.

Comment: @BillMote, will that de-duplicate checkbox only select one device? If so which one?

Comment: I knew you would ignore my questions. What's the use case? Do you anticipate that a lot of your users will have multiple devices?

Comment: Hello @BillMote. 
First of all, Yes, we anticipate that most of the users will have multiple devices regardless of device types (iOS/Android). 

Also, What we are trying to do is to send only to the device that has the most recent 'last login date' field, which we've set as a custom attribute. 

As far as I've tested, I guess push messages are basically sent based on the contact information rather than device information, no matter what we set as a pre-condition...

Comment: Thank you for the detail. Pandering this around internally.

Comment: Journey Builder MobilePush activities send on the Contact level.  Even if you do a lookup based on the device token, it will still always use ContactKey to make the send.  The only way to make a single device send would be to use the messageContact route and supply device tokens there.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postMessageContactSendPush.html